# Resize dynamic string array

Tags: c++, arrays, string, dynamic

How can I resize a dynamic multidimensional array `std::string**` in C++ without using C methods like `malloc/free`?

Comment: Why did you start out by using `std::string**`?  Why not use `std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>>`?

Comment: Can you use `new` and `delete`?

Comment: Whenever you think "dynamic array" you next thought should *always* be `std::vector`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I think that might be what OP is looking for. He seems to come from the C world, may be he is not aware of such a possibility.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I thought that `std::vector` is heavier on the memory than arrays. And I do know C++. Maybe my question would be better placed with a C tag tho.

Comment: @Kyu96 -- *I thought that std::vector is heavier on the memory than arrays.* --  All vector does is wrap what you're trying to do in a class.  The big difference is that vector is standard, well-documented, works, and in terms of speed, more than likely more efficient than what you could devise yourself.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Also, vector<vector<string>> is not an option because the entires need to be at certain positions, like on a chessboard/matrix. in a vector i can just pusback/pushfront items

Comment: @Kyu96 there are more ways to resize a `vector` than just `push_back`.  [Check out the `resize` method.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize) With a bit of looping to make sure you get all of the sub`vector`s, you're pretty much done.

Comment: The memory overhead for std::vector is typically 8 bytes. If you have more than, let's say, 4Gb of RAM, that should pose no problem.

Comment: @Kyu96 -- *the entires need to be at certain positions, like on a chessboard/matrix.* -- I have no idea what that's supposed to mean.  `matrix[x][y]` means the same thing for a 2d array as it does for `std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>`.  Also, a vector can be sized in multiple ways:  `push_back`, `resize`, `insert`, `emplace_back`, in addition to being sized on construction.

Answer (score 5):

In C++ is not possible reallocate arrays/matrices. So, if you want resize a array you need use the C function *realloc* or a combination of `new[] + copy + delete[]`.

But the best option is use the C++ standard library (`std::vector`) because allows you to insert/delete/update without think about memory reallocation.

Example (C++ 11):

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main(){
    // *using* is like a alias: when the compiler finds the type "stringVec" 
    // it will replace by "std::vector<std::string>"
    using stringVec = std::vector<std::string>;

    std::vector<stringVec> matrix;
    matrix.push_back({"1", "2", "3"}); // inserts a row
}
```

Comment: I would suggest maybe explaining (or removing) the `using` directive since OP clearly is not familiar with C++. Other than that, good answer!